# Microsoft.Lync.Model assembly not found on Asp.Net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, lync-2013, lync-client-sdk

I am writing an ASP.Net application which uses the Lync client API to get user availability state from Lync.

Now I get a strange error when calling the Lync api methods:

> "The file or assembly 'Microsoft.Lync.Model [...] not found".

But I have referenced the Lync client api in the correct version.

What do I have to change to make this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lync client api may not be an ideal fit for an ASP .Net application but that depends which of the 2 you are using.

There is one for desktop applications and one for Silverlight applications, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj933180.aspx for more details.

Regardless of which version you are using you will need the Lync client installed on that machine.  To be explicit if you are using the api on the server as I suspect then the server will need the Lync Client installed there.

It's also worth noting that there is a web api for lync https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn962133(v=office.16).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I use the client API on a server, but it should not be a problem. Lync client is installed and if I execute Unit-Tests my code works. I only get the error when starting my application.

Comment: I added the Microsoft.Lync.Model assembly to the GAC and now it works without problems.

Comment: @PhilippEger, did you just download a dll and moved it to GAC? if so did you check dll size first?

Answer (score 1):

You can find here exact instruction

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh378548%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Microsoft.Lync.Model.dll is not added to the global assembly cache on your computer during Microsoft Lync SDK installation. Instead, you must navigate to the install location of these files and select them for inclusion in your project references.

nothing more then this, if you sill have a problem maybe it's a good thing to create new application project in Visual Studio.

Hope it help.